# Binding Column of custom DataGrid to the Parent control property

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the next classes:

```
public class TestData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Calibration NewCalibration { get; set; }

    public Calibration OldCalibration { get; set; }
}

public class Calibration
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Image Image { get; set; }
}
```

I have a collection of TestData objects. Each object has 2 types of calibration.
I bind this collection in some window control to the ItemSource of the custom DataGrid control.
In the file of custom DataGrid control, I want to create the DataTemplate for the DataGridCell which will show the picture.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NewSuccess">
    <Border Padding="2">
        <Image Source="{Binding NewCalibration.Image, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="OldSuccess">
    <Border Padding="2">
        <Image Source="{Binding OldCalibration.Image, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

There is some Style where I want to change the template by some Triggers:

```
<Style x:Key="TestStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeValue} Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource NewSuccess}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeValue} Value="False">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource OldSuccess}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Also, I create some test DataTemplate which doesn't have binding to some data. It just contains the TextBlock with static text.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TestTemplate">
    <Border Padding="2">
        <TextBlock Text="Test"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

When I set the TestStyle to the DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle I don't see any of pictures described in the NewSuccess or OldSuccess template. But when I use TestTemplate in this style - I see the "Test" text. property - all works, I see the "Test" text. But when I try to set the NewSuccess or OldSuccess template - I don't see anything. It seems that it can't bind to the NewCalibration.Image or OldCalibration.Image property.
I also added RelativeSource to the binding, but it didn't help.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: How is an Image supposed to be used as the Source of an Image? Use ImageSource instead,

Comment: @Clemens I use it by Image.Source property. It works in another window without problems.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.image.source?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

But here it seems that it doesn't see NewCalibration.Image property. It looks like it tries to find it on ContentControl level. But ContentControl is placed in the DataTemplate inside the DataGridCell.

If I set the NewSuccess template to the DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate directly - it works.

Comment: It can not work. Look at the type of the Source property, it is `ImageSource`. You can use neither `System.Windows.Controls.Image` nor `System.Drawing.Image` as type of the source property of a Binding of an Image's Source property. You are confusing things here.

Comment: @Clemens Ok, nevermind. I changed the template to bind to the NewCalibration.Name or OldCalibration.Name properties. But I am also unable to get values from these properties.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding to the Binding "DataContext" and FindAncestor by the DataGridCell type:

`<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.SomeValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell}}" Value="True">`